# Generate an Variable Filled with Random Integers in R

Tags: r, random

I wish to add a random integer between 1 and 3 to mtcars.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Read the documentation for the function sample: `?sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with runif and round function.

```
mtcars$random<-round(runif(dim(mtcars)[1],1,3))
```

https://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/stat007.html

Comment: `runif` will not return integers as specified: `set.seed(1); runif(1, 1, 3)` returns `[1] 1.531017`

Comment: how about mtcars$random<-round(runif(dim(mtcars)[1],1,3), digits = 0)?